# Row selection not working while applying Data trigger on datatgrid rowstyle

Tags: wpf

i want change background color of row when one of column (ie. status) in itemsource is Open and Current and while adding below case row selection not working. is there any solution...

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">                                                    
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status}" Value="Open">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"></Setter>
                   </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status}" Value="Current">
                      <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"></Setter>
                   </DataTrigger>                                                       
               </Style.Triggers>                                                    
       </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Value` property of your `DataTrigger` use the `{x:Static}` form:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status}" 
             Value="{x:Static my:enum_status.Open}">
```

`my` is where your `enum` declared for example if you have something like this:

```
namespace MyWpfApplication.MyNamespace
{
    public enum enum_status
    {
        Close,
        Open,
        Current
    }
}
```

Then your namespace declaration would be:

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyWpfApplication.MyNamespace"
```

Comment: @user3502966 Then you should provide more details (code, explanation, etc ...) because this works fine for me.

Comment: i have created enum  `public enum enum_status{Open,Current,Close };` in my class 'test' and also added assemlby `xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Reflection.BusinessEntity;assembly=Reflection.BusinessEntity"` and used in value like this ` <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding status}" Value="{x:Static my:EPR_T001+enum_status.Open}">`

Comment: it's changing background color but in alternate manner ... ie. it's not change background of all rows whose status is open .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I wrote a simple application based on this, and it simply change color of rows with `status = open` to `DarkBlue`, rows with `status = current` to `DarkGreen` and other rows background color remain unchanged. There is no alternate manner!

Comment: If this answer did not solve your issue, then you should start over and write a very simple application only containing an `enum`, a `DataGrid` and a test data collection then see the result and compare it with your original program to see where the problem is.